# Unable to enqueue a job on Hangfire due to abstract classes/DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, hangfire, mediatr

When enqueuing a job to Hangfire, it seems like the DI is not working as it should, since it seems to be trying to instantiate a class out of an interface.

In this example, trying to enqueue a job with Hangfire that involves using a class from DI  directly within the job will result in a compilation error or runtime exception. Hangfire struggles with the abstract nature of the base class, as it can't create an instance directly.

The error output is the following:

[image]

What seems to be missing in my configuration?

Currently I have this setup:

```
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services
                .AddOptions<DatabaseOptions>()
                .BindConfiguration(DatabaseOptions.ConfigKey)
                .ValidateDataAnnotations()
                .ValidateOnStart();


            services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>((provider, builder) =>
            {
                var dbOptions = provider
                    .GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseOptions>>()
                    .Value;

                    builder
                        .UseNpgsql(dbOptions.Postgres.ConnectionString,
                            options => { options.CommandTimeout(dbOptions.Postgres.CommandTimeoutInSeconds); })
                        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
          
            });

            services.AddDbContext<EventStoreDbContext>((provider, builder) =>
            {
                var dbOptions = provider
                    .GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseOptions>>()
                    .Value;
                    builder
                        .UseNpgsql(dbOptions.Postgres.ConnectionString,
                            options => { options.CommandTimeout(dbOptions.Postgres.CommandTimeoutInSeconds); })
                        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
            });

            services.AddHangfire((provider, configuration) =>
            {
                var dbOptions = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseOptions>>().Value;

                configuration.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170);

            services.AddHangfireServer((provider, globalConfig) =>
            {
               
            });

            services.AddTransient<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
            
            services.AddBlockchainInfrastructure();
          
        });

        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code where you actually create the job?

Comment: This is not issue with hangfire. Hangfire uses AspNetCoreActivator to resolve dependencies of your job  ( Microsoft DI) , and one of your dependencies is abstract class.